# Conan Error: Library 'boost_log_setup' not found in package when calling conan install from a dockerfile

Tags: docker, boost, conan

When attempting to conan install my dependencies from inside a dockerfile used to set up a docker container, I get the error `Library 'boost_log_setup' not found in package`. Once inside the container, if I manually delete the build folder then conan install again, the error is fixed and my dependencies are resolved. I would like for this extra step to not be necessary.

conanfile.py

```
import os

from conan import ConanFile
from conan.tools.cmake import CMakeToolchain, CMake, cmake_layout
from conan.tools.files import get
from conan.tools.build import check_min_cppstd

class DataFusionEngineRecipe(ConanFile):
    name = 'data-fusion-engine'

    settings = 'os', 'compiler', 'build_type', 'arch'
    options = {
        'shared': [True, False],
        'fPIC': [True, False]
    }

    default_options = {
        'shared': False,
        'fPIC': True
    }

    generators = 'CMakeDeps'

    exports_sources = 'CMakeLists.txt', 'src/*'

    def validate(self):
        check_min_cppstd(self, '20')

    def requirements(self):
        self.requires('sofa/20210512')
        self.requires('cspice/0067')
        self.requires('eigen/3.4.0')
        self.requires('nlohmann_json/3.11.2')
        self.requires('boost/1.74.0')
        self.requires('murty-algorithm/1.0.1')
        self.requires('benchmark/1.8.2')

    def build_requirements(self):
        self.test_requires('gtest/1.13.0')
        self.tool_requires('cmake/3.27.0')

    def config_options(self):
        if self.settings.os == 'Windows':
            del self.options.fPIC

    def configure(self):
        if self.options.shared:
            self.options.rm_safe('fPIC')

    def layout(self):
        cmake_layout(self)

    def generate(self):
        tc = CMakeToolchain(self)
        tc.generate()

    def build(self):
        cmake = CMake(self)
        cmake.configure()
        cmake.build()
        if not self.conf.get('tools.build:skip_test', default=False):
            import os

    def package(self):
        cmake = CMake(self)
        cmake.install(self)

    def package_info(self):
        self.cpp_info.libs = ['data_fusion_engine']
        self.cpp_info.includedirs = ['include']
        self.cpp_info.libdirs = ['lib']
```

conan command in dockerfile

```
conan install . --build="*" -s compiler.cppstd=gnu20
```

local conan profile

```
Host profile:
[settings]
arch=x86_64
build_type=Release
compiler=gcc
compiler.cppstd=gnu17
compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11
compiler.version=11
os=Linux
```

conan profile in container

```
Host profile:
[settings]
arch=x86_64
build_type=Release
compiler=gcc
compiler.cppstd=gnu14
compiler.libcxx=libstdc++
compiler.version=10
os=Linux
```

- I have tried making a `conan.lock` file, but that did not work
- I have tried deleting the build folder inside the dockerfile, but that did not work
- I have tried cleaning the conan cache inside the dockerfile, but that did not work
- I have tried matching the conan profiles in and outside the container via `-s` flags in the conan install command, but that did not work

Comment: A couple of suggestions: maybe better report it in https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues, but with a bit more of detail: the Conan version, a reduced ``conanfile.py`` (most likely it can be reproduced with a very simple conanfile.py with only the ``boost`` dependency). I would say that the boost specific version could be related and try with other boost versions.